# Как правильно отрезать время от даты?

Tags: дата, время, java

Есть объект Date. Нужно от него отрезать временную часть. Ну например 22:22 11.11.2011 должно переделаться в 00:00 11.11.2011. Написал так:

```
Date startO = new Date(String.valueOf(start.getDate() + '.' + (start.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + start.getYear() )); //собирается строка 11.11.2011 и отдаётся на распарсинье конструктору Date -а (Date start --> Date startO)
```

Разумеется такому коду место только [сюда](http://govnokod.ru). Он медлен и тормознут, да и логически глуп. **Подскажите как переписать его?**

p.s. в данном случае мне важна скорость

p.p.s. да, я знаю, что Date is deprectaed, но мне всё равно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date someDate = ... ;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(someDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: И как я не догадался. Только зачем переводить в календарь, если можно start.setSeconds?